# Video uploading with Codeigniter and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, video

I tried many ways to upload Videos through my website. I don't know why, I can save images, text files etc. but it is not possible to save videos into the folder and database.

Here is my view.

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>galleries/add_vdo" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="input-group">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Title" name="vdo_title" id="vdo_title"> 
                 <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="About Video"  name="vdo_desc" id="vdo_desc"></textarea>

                <input class="" name="ur_vdo" id="ur_vdo" type="file">

                <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Now"/>
                <!--<button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="submit" type="button">Invite</button>-->

                </div>
                </form>
```

controller:

```
  function add_vdo()
  {
   $data['ur_vdo'] = $this->gallery_model->add_new_vdos(); 
   redirect('galleries/vdo_gal','refresh');
  }
```

Model :

```
 function add_new_vdos()
 {
 $this->load->helper('date');
 date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
 $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/myvideos/';
 $config['allowed_types'] = 'mp4|avi|flv|wmv|';                   

$this->load->library('upload', $config);
                    $this->upload->initialize($config);
                    $field_name ="ur_vdo";
                    $rgpic="0";
                    if ( !$this->upload->do_upload($field_name))
                    {
                    $error = $this->upload->display_errors();
                    $data['error']=$error;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    $data = $this->upload->data();
                    $regpicname=$data['file_name'];
                    $rgpic="1";
                    }
                      if($rgpic!=0)
                   {

                    $dts = array(
                           'familypost_caption'=>$this->input->post('vdo_title'),
                           'familypost_desc'=>$this->input->post('vdo_title'),
                           'user_id' =>$uid,
                           'familypost_vdo'=>$regpicname,
                           'familypost_status'=>'A',
                           'familypost_date'=>now()
                           );
                   }
                   else
                   {
                    $dts = array(
                           'familypost_caption'=>$this->input->post('vdo_title'),
                           'familypost_desc'=>$this->input->post('vdo_title'),
                           'user_id' =>$uid,
                           'familypost_status'=>'A',
                           'familypost_date'=>now()
                           );
                        }   

                $vdqr = $this->db->insert('roottildb_familyposts',$dts);       
}
```

I don't know why, video upload fails without showing any error. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Check your upload limit in php.ini

Comment: You have set `$data['error']=$error;` but didn't used it. Print it to see if you get the error.

Comment: videos are always bigger than pics, right?